# How to handle JSON key with dollar sign with jq at Powershell?

Tags: json, powershell, jq

Here is the `jq` command like below: `jq '.. |."$ref"? | select(. != null)'`
It works in [jq player](https://jqplay.org/s/3eyOJRRyTu)

How do I run this command in Powershell?

I want to get all returned values to a variable in PowerShell (list/array).

I have tried:

- `jq '.. |.'$ref'? | select(. != null)' .\swagger.json` --> I get everything in json file.
- `jq '.. |."$ref"? | select(. != null)' .\swagger.json` --> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
  .. |.$ref? | select(. != null)

How to get this jq command to work in Powershell?
Thanks

Comment: `jq '.. |.\"$ref\"? | select(. != null)'` works (in PowerShell 7 on Linux, at least). There are rules governing this, but I have basically given up trying to understand how they work across platforms.

Comment: Which version of jq are you using with PowerShell?

Comment: @peak, I use jq version 1.6 in PowerShell 3

Comment: Have you tried DOS-style quotation marks, along the lines of `jq ".. |.\"$ref\"? | select(. != null)"`

Comment: @peak That will cause `$ref` to be expanded by the shell.

Comment: I got it working with `jq '.. |.\"$ref\"? | select(. != null)'` Can't tell you why given *A string enclosed in single-quotation marks is a verbatim string. The string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. No substitution is performed.*

Comment: Sending double quotes to external programs is a problem for powershell.  A jq script would avoid quoting issues.

Answer (score 0):

`jq '.. |.\"$ref\"? | select(. != null)'` works with PowerShell version 5.1.1941.1682 on Windows 10. Note the single quotes around the argument and the backslashes before the double quotes.

If it doesn't, create a text file with the jq program (the string inside the quotes) and then run `jq -f program.jq`. This avoids any quoting or escaping issues of your shell, you can write the jq program verbatim, just as you would on [jq play](https://jqplay.org).

NB: `select(. != null)` can be written more succinctly as `select(values)`